# Laravel list with unique values and count of values

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Im trying show unique values from database with count of them in table view. But i have problem count them.

```
id | name  |
------------
 1 | john  |
 2 | john  |
 3 | smith |
```

my goal is show in table

```
name     count
---------------
john       2
smith      1
```

`my controller`

```
    $usersList = DB::table('users')->distinct('name')->get('name');
    
    //dd($usersList);

    return view('dashboard', compact('data'))->with(['usersList '=> $usersList]);
```

`dd($userList)` show 1 `john` and 1 `smith`

`dashboard.blade`

```
 @foreach ($usersList as $row)
       <tr>
           <th scope="row">{{ $row ->name }}</th>                            
           <td>{{ $row->count('name') }}</td>
       </tr>
 @endforeach
```

`error` : `Call to undefined method stdClass::count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$users = User::distinct()->get(['name']);
$users_count = [];
foreach ($users AS $user) {
    $user_count = User::where('name', $user->name)->count('name');
    $users_count[] = $user_count;
}
```

And in your blade use this code:

```
@foreach ($users AS $user_key => $user_value)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            {{ $user_value->name }}
        </th>                            
        <td>
            {{ $users_count[$user_key] }}
        </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller:

```
$usersList = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('name as name, count(*) as 'count'  GROUP BY name'))->get();
```

and in your *.blade.php file

```
    @foreach ($usersList as $row)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $row->name }}</th>                            
        <td>{{ $row->count }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

here is the laravel documentation about DB facade and selects : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

you can test queries like this in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b70e/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `countBy` as follows:

```php
$users = User::select('name')->get()->countBy('name');
```

And in your blade use:

```php
@foreach ($users AS $user_key => $user_value)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            {{ $user_value->name }}
        </th>                            
        <td>
            {{ $users_count[$user_key] }}
        </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

[See laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-countBy)